# Fix Failed to Open a Session for the Virtual Machine Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS

Tags: virtual-machine

While Starting the VM after a abort and also had a some windows 10 updates done during this period. then I start receiving this error.

**Fix Failed to Open a Session for the Virtual Machine Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS**

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for **Turn Windows features on or off**

[image]

2. Uncheck Hyper-V option and Restart

Then it started working